# Python: function stops after only part of it has run

Tags: python, function

I am working on a hangman project and have run into a problem where the main function only runs for part of its entirety, then it stops.  I made a smaller version of my original project to focus on the problem more.

```
import re
import time
import sys

#hangman shows the player how many incorrect guesses they did
hangman =['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
print('\n')

w = input ('type what word you want to guess:     ')
for i in range(50):
  print('\n')

#blank_list creates a blank list from the word they choose above.  It takes all letters and 
     #turns them into underscores, while special characters are exempt. 

blank_list = []
blank_list = re.sub('A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z', '_', w)
blank_list = ' '.join(blank_list)   

incorrect = 0

def guesscounter(w,blank_list,incorrect):
#main loop, lets player input their guess
  while incorrect < 7:
    print(hangman[incorrect])
    print(blank_list)
    guess = input('What letter would you like to guess?     ').upper 
    #this is where it stops
    return guess
    for i in range(50):
      print('\n')
#makes a player only guess one letter or get penalized
    if guess > 0:
      print("Ummmm, you can't guess more than one letter at a time. . . Have you played hangman before?")
      incorrect = incorrect + 1
      return incorrect
      for i in range(50):
        print('\n')
#determines whether guess is in word
    if w.count(guess) == -1:
      incorrect = incorrect+1
      print("Sorry, {} isn't in the word. Try again!".format(guess))
      time.sleep(3)
      for i in range(50):
        print('\n')
#replaces a blank with its letter when the player guesses correctly
    else:
      print('Good job! you got one!')
      locate = w.find(guess)
      blank_list.insert(guess,locate)
      return blank_list
      time.sleep(3)
      for i in range(50):
          print('\n')
#tells when the player guesses all of the letters
    if blank_list.count('_') == -1:
      print('Wow, you win! Nice job!')
      sys.exit
#tells when the player runs out of chances
  while incorrect == 7:
    print('You lose!  The word was {}! Better luck next time'.format(w))
guesscounter(w,blank_list,incorrect)
```

it currently only runs the first section guesscounter, from the top of the function to the guess input (when it ends, the shell says that guess is not defined).  I will answer any questions that you have to the best of my abilities.

Comment: Stopping the function is precisely what the `return` statement *does*.  What were you expecting it to do otherwise?

Comment: Add parentheses to `.upper()`

Comment: Did you just want to *print* the value of `guess`? `print` and `return` are two very different things.

Comment: @jasonharper oops, I didn't know return did that.  I put the return there to update Guess when the function loops, so that Guess wouldn't keep the first input and then not change.  I'll try to fix it and then I'll update the post

Answer (score 1):

In your `guesscounter` function, after you ask the user/player "What letter would you like to guess?", in the next line you do `return guess`. That returns the value in the function, an explicit return statement immediately terminates a function execution and sends the return value back to the caller code. (you can read more here: https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/). So it doesn't look like you really need that return statement because the code below that is always unreachable, unless there is a reason you can comment on?